# Loop from list using unirest in python

Tags: python, unirest

I'm looking to loop print synonyms for each item from my list

```
myList = ["First", "Second", "Third"]
```

tried few loop methods with no success, please help

to print them manually 1 by 1 the command is

```
response = unirest.get("https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/first/synonyms", headers={ "X-Mashape-Key": "**MY -Mashape-Key", "Accept": "application/json" } )
```

**response.body** <===this will print synonyms for word "first"

How do i loop to print the body for all the words in my list ? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the example json output? We do not have any api key for this website.

Comment: i can share you a private key in private to test if you want , i really appreaciate this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
for word in myList
    response = unirest.get("https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/" + word + "/synonyms", headers={ "X-Mashape-Key": "API_KEY", "Accept": "application/json" } )
    print response.body
```

I don't know Python, but from its documentation, it seems it should work.

Comment: This was the first order that i tried as well but it says TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Comment: @totheM The error means that `word` is a list object. So you shoud check if  `myList` is a list of lists.

Comment: It was mostly my error trying unirest.post instead of unirest.get